# Best way to add properties for a product in a database (with EntityFramework, c#)

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, properties

For exmaple there is a table *drink*. A drink has different properties with a value (protein: 6g, sugar: 5g...).

The properties can vary between the different drinks.

What's the best way to implement this example in a database?

An implementing-example:

```
public class Drink : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DrinkProperty> DrinkProperties{ get; set; }
    }



public class DrinkProperty : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual Drink Drink { get; set; }

        public virtual Property Property { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

public class Property : BaseEntity
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Measure Measure { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DrinkProperty> DrinkProperties { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Put code what you tried so far for better understanding.

Comment: This is called an EAV model. You should be really 100% sure you want this because it's not a nice model to work with, esp. for querying. Storing data in a non-relational database (like ravendb, mongodb) might be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need a many to many relationship because one drink can have multiple properties and each of the properties can be given to different drinks. So many to many relation with a column for the quantity of the property in the drink. 
What you can do is make a stored procedure in the database and then just connect to it with c# and execute it by giving it some parameters. 
Because you will probably don't how many products you will have in this drink you can just add them as one big nvarchar and then split with some function in the database. Or you can add many parameters which will null by default and then take only the one that are not null.